# Updating Microsoft.NETCore.App to v1.1.0 causes -2147450749 (0x80008083)

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I created a new .NET Core project in Visual Studio 2015 by following the instructions at: https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowsvs2015

It works OK, and I can add breakpoints etc. no problem.

Then I ran Tools->NuGet Package Manager->Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...

I got the option to update Microsoft.NETCore.App to the latest stable release v1.1.0.

The first issue I got was the error:

**Can not find runtime target for framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0' compatible with one of the target runtimes: 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win8-x64, win7-x64'.**

This appeared to be due to the update removing lines from the project.json, so I added the missing lines back in and changed the version to 1.1.0, so my project.json now looks like this:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.1.0"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```

The program then built without issue, but when I run the program I get the Error:

**The program '[13048] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -2147450749 (0x80008083).**

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post your entire `project.json`?

Comment: Please see updated question with full 'project.json'. I could also add 'project.lock.json' but that is quite big.

Comment: Have you install the .NET Core 1.1 SDK ?  https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core (You can see the version on .NET you are using with this command in the package manager : dotnet --info)

Comment: Thanks @Adrien that was the issue.

Comment: @greg-barlow Welcome :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Adrien for providing the solution.

In the package Manager Console I ran the command:

**dotnet --info**

Response was:

**.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-003131)**

So I installed the .NET Core 1.1 SDK from:

https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core

Now I get the response:

**.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)**

I think the versioning information is quite confusing as I don't see how this relates to 1.1.0, but the console application runs OK.

Thanks again.

Comment: The versioning is quite confusing because dotnet --info command gives you the version of the CLI, which is used to build the dotnet core app and not the version of the dotnet core framework itself.