# Host ASP.NET Core on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to host an asp.net core web application, but for some reason it wont work. My other core app's work, but not this one. I've set the application pool .net clr version to no managed code.

this is what I get in event viewer:
"Application 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST/FFU CORE' with physical root 'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WWWROOT\Customer\core_FFU\' failed to start process with commandline '"dotnet" .\WEB_CORE_MODERN_2017.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008083."

any help will be higly appreciated!

Comment: Quick google search of your error code reveals it's could be a bad runtime: https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling/issues/886

Comment: Mark as answer, if the answer has the solution

Answer (score 0):

1. Can you host via IIS Express in Visual Studio?
2. Are you updated to the latest SDK and runtime? https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/download-archive.md
3. Make sure you have the latest .net core windows hosting installed.

Similar question: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916596/updating-microsoft-netcore-app-to-v1-1-0-causes-2147450749-0x80008083)

Comment: sounds like you where right! Installed the latest runtime and everything worked :) thanks for the help!